# Язык php, c чего начать?

Tags: php

Хочу научится Php. Я не программист и не знаю ничего о языках. Но постараюсь научиться. Скажите, с чего начать Php. Что такое операторы и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: Как говорил один из преподавателей - Открываете учебник, и вам все становится ясно!  
  
Невозможно, чтобы вы на форуме прям так и научились азам.

Comment: советую очень хорошо подумать над выбором первого языка, вы уверены что именно php?

Вообще я бы посоветовал сначала определится что именно вам интересно, на уровне прочтения пары статей узнать о других языках. 

Потом взвесить все за и против и выбрать, по поводу с чего начать - начать надо не с книги а с цели.

"Я не программист и не знаю ничего о языках" вообщем прямо сейчас начните с этого.

Ах да - если вы все-таки соберетесь учить php - необходимо как минимум знание html (хотя, имхо, его должны знать вообще все уважающие себя разработчики)

Comment: Добавлю к сказанному @AlexWindHope. Я ориентировался на выборе того, что принесет мне большую прибыль, в не зависимости от того, нравится мне это или нет. И не жалею. Потому что все языки хороши.

Comment: Я ориентировался на выборе того, что принесет мне большую прибыль

Обычно такие люди не получают большу`ю прибыль. Но и не бомжуют естественно =)

Я просто к тому что важно любить свое дело, тогда можно чего-то достичь(всмысле чего-то большего чем **абсолютно** заслуженую з/п), да и как говорил один из классиков (к своему стыду не помню кто это был, ну да не суть):

       Если работа будет нравится, работы больше не будет

Comment: Нужно начинать с простого примера [Hello World!]( http://www.phppatterns.com/docs/design/hello_world_in_patterns)

Comment: Начните и изучения python

Answer (score 3):

Читай всё по порядку [тут](http://php.su/php/?php)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.softtime.ru/bookphp/gl1_1.php 
http://php720.com/index.php
Первый онлайн учебник тебе поможет быстро разобраться со основами, а вот второй уже чуть по сильней учебник, но оба написаны они на нормальном, досигаемом языке который можно читать и понимать о чем речь! я бы тебе посоветовал скачать еще, если скорость интернета позволяет, PHP+MYSQL ДЛЯ НАЧИНАЮЩИХ, это видео курс Попова Евгения, который конечно хороший, но везде пишут что он много ошибок в своих доводов приводит, но зато Пацан объясняет все так, что всем все понятно, есть могу посоветовать видео курс PHP уровень 1 от Специалиста, пока что, для освоение как раз нормально, всего 4-ре уровня) думаю когда ты откроешь учебник, то у тебя не будет вопрос что такое операторы. я тоже начинающий php кодер, месяца полтора, когда я начал изучать html я и знать не знал что такое php

Comment: @Sleepik Как-бы после изучения курсов Попова человек пойдет по его рекомендациям и ему будет трудно что-то вбить в голову - он будет стоять на своем, и вообще изучать язык нужно не просто почитал и забыл, а с постановки какой-то определенной цели например какой нибудь форум сваять (конечно про форум я уж слишком загнул =) но все же) так, что придумай, что ты хочешь добиться и ищи по кусочкам информацию, и научишься и из головы полученная инфа не вылитет, но а вот про азы всеже просто где нибудь почитай, если будут проблемы то пиши сюда тебе тут с радостью помогут братишь)))

Answer (score 0):

есть книгаd "php 5 в подлиннике" Дмитрия Котерова, Алексея Костарева, кратко, ясно, не грузит

Answer (score 0):

С молитвы и 100 отжиманий на кулаках. А серьезно: было бы желание, остальное приложиться. Нужно учиться программировать, а не учить язык. Если научитесь,любой язык будет "работать" на вас

Answer (score -1):

[Учебник по PHP 4](http://www.softtime.ru/bookphp/gl1_1.php) Это, если Вам именно учебник нужен. Как раз азы объясняются, я с него начинал, правда, тогда я уже был знаком с несколькими языками программирования. Заметьте, что книга по PHP 4, так что послле её изучения нужно будет про ООП почитать и PHP 5.

Comment: Зачем же Вы советуете книги по 4ке? Это раз а во вторых, если человек ничего не знает о программировании то скорее всего ему нужно прочитать книги по основам программирования.

Answer (score -1):

Есть очень хороший видео курс от Евгения Попова "Все Технические Моменты Онлайн Бизнеса в Видеоформате 2 или PHP+MySQL для начинающих" и книги Стивена Хольцнера. 
С этого начинал я.

Comment: Видео курсы всегда лучше запоминаются так как там объясняют все на пальцах